# Is it possible to mix declarative and imperative paradigms for Android UI development?

Tags: android, declarative, imperative

Is it possible to mix declarative and imperative paradigms for Android UI development ?

1- In « traditional » Android development, Java + XML are used to create interface elements (in a Rather static way).

2- With Kotlin + « Jetpack Compose » it is possible to create UI elements dynamically.

Is there a way to mix and match 1. And 2. ?

Answer (score 1):

[ComposeView](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/ComposeView) in traditional android or [AndroidView](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/viewinterop/package-summary) in compose

Comment: Thank you very much !